# Circular dependency angularjs

Tags: angularjs, circular-dependency

can anyone tell me where is the circular dependency in the following code?

```
var homeApp = angular.module("homeApp",['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

'use strict';

homeApp.factory('AdminDashboardService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){


    return {


        'response': function(response) {
              // do something on success
              console.log("Yes Command comes here");
              return response;
            },

        getAllHolidays: function(monthYearArrayForHolidayList) {
            console.log("For full list of holidays list length: "+monthYearArrayForHolidayList.length);
            var isMonthly="no";
            return $http.get('/tasktrac/holiday/getHoliday/isMonthly/'+isMonthly+'/'+monthYearArrayForHolidayList)
                    .then(
                            function(response){
                                return response.data;
                            }, 
                            function(errResponse){
                                //console.error('Error while fetching holiday');
                                return $q.reject(errResponse);
                            }
                    );
    },
}]);


homeApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AdminDashboardService');
}]);
```

I am stuck at this point please do me a favour in resolving this issue.
This is the Error I got on the browser
[Please click here to see error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/cdep?p0=$http%20%3C-%20AdminDashboardService%20%3C-%20$http%20%3C-%20$templateRequest%20%3C-%20$compile%22)
Thank you..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A $http interceptor could not declare $http as a dependency!

Inject $injector:

```
homeApp.factory('AdminDashboardService', ['$injector', '$q', function($injector, $q){


    return {


        'response': function(response) {
              // do something on success
              console.log("Yes Command comes here");
              return response;
            },

        getAllHolidays: function(monthYearArrayForHolidayList) {
            console.log("For full list of holidays list length: "+monthYearArrayForHolidayList.length);
            var isMonthly="no";
            return $injector.get("$http").get('/tasktrac/holiday/getHoliday/isMonthly/'+isMonthly+'/'+monthYearArrayForHolidayList)
                    .then(
                            function(response){
                                return response.data;
                            }, 
                            function(errResponse){
                                //console.error('Error while fetching holiday');
                                return $q.reject(errResponse);
                            }
                    );
    },
}]);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further, I am sorry I am new to angular js, Can you tell me what exactly I need to do, I did not understand the answer, Please suggest me changes in my code

Comment: posted fixed code, no much to explain: $http injection replaced with $injector. If you are new to angular be sure to understand Dependecy Injection concepts

Comment: I am getting this error  [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=httpProvider%20%3C-%20http

Comment: Am I not supposed to add  "homeApp.config(...)" ??

Comment: check "$injector.get("$http")" spelling, look like missing the $ prefix